Iterate template sub-control
I have this custom control:
<dxga:RadialGauge WidthRequest="350" HeightRequest="220">
    <dxga:RadialScale StartAngle="180" 
        StartValue="0" EndValue="{Binding ScaleSettings.ScaleEndValue}" 
        ShowTickmarkLabels="True"
        MajorTickmarkCount="5"
        MinorTickmarkCount="4"
        SweepAngle="180"
        Fill="Transparent"
        TickmarkLabelPosition="Inside">
        <dxga:RangeIndicator StartValue="0" EndValue="{Binding ScaleSettings.ScaleFirstStep}" StrokeCap="Square" StartThickness="20" Fill="#EEEEEE" />

        [ ... ]

    </dxga:RadialScale>
</dxga:RadialGauge>

At the [ ... ] position I would like to iterate through an ObservableCollection using a sub-control:
<dxga:MarkerIndicator Value="{Binding .}"/>
Is that in any way possible?
UPDATE
Through the code behind I can add the necessary needles/markers by:
<dxga:RadialScale x:Name="scale"></dxga:RadialScale>

and
scale.Indicators.Add(new MarkerIndicator()
{
    Value = 50
});

However, my data is in the code behind. What is the best way to get the data from the viewmodel to the code behind?

Your question is a bit unclear do you want to iterate through all the subcontrols of a control?

I want the <dxga:MarkerIndicator Value="XX" /> to be added X number of times from an ObservableCollection.

the code-behind has a reference to the ViewModel via BindingContext

Yeah, so you would just reference the same ObservableObject in viewmodel as well as code-behind?

You can create a Viewmodel to set the data directly. It does not need to pass the data to the code behind.
 public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int num;
    public int Num
    {
        get => num;
        set
        {
            num = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(num));
        }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        num = 50;
    }
      
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}

Then, you can set the bindingcontext for the ContentPage. Due to the Gets or set of the ValueIndicatorBase descendant’s value, this is a bindable property. Inherited from ValueIndicatorBase. So, you can bind the Num to the value.
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModel:VM/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

<dxga:MarkerIndicator Value="{Binding Num}"/>


Yeah thanks, but that's not what I need. I need to add <dxga:MarkerIndicator Value="{Binding Num[0]}"/><dxga:MarkerIndicator Value="{Binding Num[1]}"/><dxga:MarkerIndicator Value="{Binding Num[n]}"/>
